# nvd3 axis ticks appear and disappear when useInteractiveGuideline is true

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

So I don't know if anyone else experienced that.

I am creating some line Charts using nvd3. If the useInteractiveGuideline is true, when I hover over the lines, the little tooltip appears as it was supposed to, but somehow it messes up with some of the axis ticks causing them to either disappear or not appear properly.

And it's just a matter of zooming in/out, scrolling up/down to restore the ticks.

I am just using the javascript code in nvd3 live code website.

```
    nv.addGraph(function() {
    var chart = nv.models.lineChart()
.useInteractiveGuideline(true)
;

 chart.xAxis
.axisLabel('Time (ms)')
.tickFormat(d3.format(',r'))
;

chart.yAxis
.axisLabel('Voltage (v)')
.tickFormat(d3.format('.02f'))
;

 d3.select('#chart svg')
.datum(data)
.transition().duration(500)
.call(chart)
;

nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

return chart;
});
```

and with data:

```
    [
{
"values": [
  {
    "x": 1347663600,
    "y": 1.2790000438690186
  },
  {
    "x": 1350255600,
    "y": 1.2717000246047974
  },
  {
    "x": 1352937600,
    "y": 1.262649953365326
  },
  {
    "x": 1355529600,
    "y": 1.287500023841858
  },
  {
    "x": 1358208000,
    "y": 1.2908499836921692
  },
  {
    "x": 1360886400,
    "y": 1.267799973487854
  },
  {
    "x": 1363305600,
    "y": 1.350600004196167
  },
  {
    "x": 1365980400,
    "y": 1.3437999486923218
  },
  {
    "x": 1368572400,
    "y": 1.343999981880188
  },
  {
    "x": 1371250800,
    "y": 1.344099998474121
  },
  {
    "x": 1373842800,
    "y": 1.3225199580192566
  },
  {
    "x": 1376521200,
    "y": 1.3444000482559204
  },
  {
    "x": 1379199600,
    "y": 1.3273500204086304
  },
  {
    "x": 1381791600,
    "y": 1.3446999788284302
  },
  {
    "x": 1384473600,
    "y": 1.347499966621399
  },
  {
    "x": 1387065600,
    "y": 1.3476499915122986
  },
  {
    "x": 1389744000,
    "y": 1.350600004196167
  },
  {
    "x": 1392422400,
    "y": 1.3508000373840332
  },
  {
    "x": 1394841600,
    "y": 1.3692998886108398
  },
  {
    "x": 1397516400,
    "y": 1.381890058517456
  },
  {
    "x": 1400108400,
    "y": 1.3828500509262085
  },
  {
    "x": 1402786800,
    "y": 1.4433000087738037
  }
],
"key": "Median Senior OC",
"color": "#f9b800"
 },
 {
 "values": [
  {
    "x": 1347663600,
    "y": 1.149999976158142
  },
  {
    "x": 1350255600,
    "y": 1.149999976158142
  },
  {
    "x": 1352937600,
    "y": 1.149999976158142
  },
  {
    "x": 1355529600,
    "y": 1.1430000066757202
  },
  {
    "x": 1358208000,
    "y": 1.149999976158142
  },
  {
    "x": 1360886400,
    "y": 1.149999976158142
  },
  {
    "x": 1363305600,
    "y": 1.1459999680519104
  },
  {
    "x": 1365980400,
    "y": 1.149999976158142
  },
  {
    "x": 1368572400,
    "y": 1.149999976158142
  },
  {
    "x": 1371250800,
    "y": 1.149999976158142
  },
  {
    "x": 1373842800,
    "y": 1.149999976158142
  },
  {
    "x": 1376521200,
    "y": 1.149999976158142
  },
  {
    "x": 1379199600,
    "y": 1.1509999632835388
  },
  {
    "x": 1381791600,
    "y": 1.149999976158142
  },
  {
    "x": 1384473600,
    "y": 1.1509999632835388
  },
  {
    "x": 1387065600,
    "y": 1.149999976158142
  },
  {
    "x": 1389744000,
    "y": 1.149999976158142
  },
  {
    "x": 1392422400,
    "y": 1.149999976158142
  },
  {
    "x": 1394841600,
    "y": 1.149999976158142
  },
  {
    "x": 1397516400,
    "y": 1.149999976158142
  },
  {
    "x": 1400108400,
    "y": 1.149999976158142
  },
  {
    "x": 1402786800,
    "y": 1.149999976158142
  }
],
"key": "Median Trigger",
"color": "#34418f"
}
]
```

My apologies for not putting a jsfiddle but the code is exactly the same as the 
http://nvd3.org/livecode . The only difference is that instead of `.datum(data())`
I have `.datum(data)`.

Thank you

Comment: I don't notice any flicker or redraw problems.  What browser/OS are you using?

Comment: Hey @AmeliaBR thanks for the comment. I am using Linux Mint 17. It's indeed happening just in Firefox. But it's still a big problem.

Comment: Could you put you code on a fiddle to have a look.

Comment: @shabeer90 As I said, If you just go to the livecode page, with firefox and put the json data above you will see it. Thanks

Comment: Must be specific to the Firefox/Linux implementation: no problems with FF31 on Win7.  You might want to add the Firefox and Linux tags (and edit the question title) to attract experts in specific implementation bugs.  Any more details about exactly what happens could also help.